# Setting up Sunspot Solr on AMI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, amazon-ec2, sunspot

I am trying to setup a development version of my app (RoR 4.0, Sunspot) on EC2 instance which run AMI. I have `gem install sunspot_solr` and then `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`

It seems like sunspot started normally. I can also access it via the web interface. Then the problem came, there's an 500 internal Server Error whenever I am trying to add a new object:

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error Error: {'responseHeader'=>{'status'=>500,'QTime'=>3},'error'=>{'msg'=>'no segments* file found in NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory@/home/ec2-user/rails-projects/local-development/solr/development/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@6b01af7; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0): files: [write.lock]','trace'=>'org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory@/home/ec2-user/rails-projects/local-development/solr/development/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@6b01af7; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0): files: [write.lock] at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:741) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:630) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:343) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:673) at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:77) at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:64) at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:192) at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:106) at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:153) at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69) Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><add><doc><field name=\"id\">Post 4</field><field name=\"type\">Post</field><field name=\"type\">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name=\"class_name\">Post</field><field name=\"subject_text\"/><field name=\"subject_text\">Van Gogh in London</field><field name=\"description_text\"/><field name=\"description_text\">Testing Experience for Van Gogh.&#13;\n&#13;\nVincent Willem van Gogh was a post-Impressionist painter of Dutch origin whose work—notable for its rough beauty, emotional honesty, and bold color—had a far-reaching influence on 20th-century art. Wikipedia&#13;\nBorn: March 30, 1853, Zundert, Netherlands&#13;\nDied: July 29, 1890, Auvers-sur-Oise, France&#13;\nPeriod: Post-Impressionism&#13;\nSiblings: Theo van Gogh, Wil van Gogh, Vincent Van Gogh, more&#13;\nParents: Anna Carbentus van Gogh, Theodorus van Gogh</field><field name=\"tagline_text\"/><field name=\"tagline_text\"/></doc></add>" Backtrace: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:283:in `adapt_response' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation' (eval):2:in `post' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:82:in `update' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:102:in `add'
```

Then I tried to reindex the sunspot for troubleshooting. It returns a similar error:

```
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - ignoring...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - ignoring...
```

From the web-interface, it seems like it is something related to Dataimport Handler? When I clicked into the DIH for my core, it shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">2</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="trace">java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.showFromFileSystem(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:212)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.ShowFileRequestHandler.handleRequestBody(ShowFileRequestHandler.java:122)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1797)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:637)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:343)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)    
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
</str><int name="code">500</int></lst>
</response>
```

I just followed the Quick Start guide on the Sunspot site and it was working just fine on the local machine. The way I set it up is exactly the same on the EC2 but it just doesn't work. As a result, I think it is not related to DIH (Since I have not defined DIH config on local machine as well).

I have been searching for a solution for two days but no luck.... Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Thank you